# Why is NHibernate's adonet.batch_size setting ignored - session.SetBachSize() throws exception?

Tags: nhibernate, exception, batch-file, bulk

I am using NHibernate and switched from my local SQLExpress database to Oracle11g.

My code started to complain. The session objects method SetBatchSize() throws a System.NotSupported exception:

> > No batch size was defined for the session factory, batching is disabled. Set adonet.batch_size = 1 to enable batching.

It worked on the SQLExpress database. Ok, so I added this

```
<property name="adonet.batch_size">1</property>
```

to the config but it still throws the same exception. The sessions Batcher property is set to this

> > Value: {NHibernate.AdoNet.NonBatchingBatcher}
> >
> > Type: NHibernate.Engine.IBatcher {NHibernate.AdoNet.NonBatchingBatcher}

It does not make any difference if i try to set the batch size in- or outside the transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NHibernate has only batcher for some RDBMs. if it doesn't find one for the database in question it defaults to nonbatchingbatcher which is not able to batch at all. you could implement your own `IBatcher`.

Comment: So oracle xe does not have a batcher and i should just try/catch around the SetBatchSize() call

Comment: can't you just specify one global batch_size or do you really need to override it with SetBatchSize()?

Comment: I have done this and now I know that I should always try/catch SetBatchSize() if i still want to use it